# Android: Unable to login to a web session and parse XML data using DOM on the same login session

Tags: android

Android Development: I'm needing to log into a web session using POST, then make another request of which I parse XML to get Lat/Long, then submit this to a google maps overlay.

My issue is I'm able to log into my system, but when I submit a command to parse XML, it is acting like a completely new session and I basically get an 'incorrect login' reply from the server.

Does anyone have some simple steps to perform this...and to keep a session open for as many commands as I need?  I'm not actually SURE I'm using a session cookie, but believe this is the case.

Some example code may be:

```
try { 
URI loginUri = new URI("http://www.mywebsite.com/ExternalLogin.jsp?user=lee&pwd=bluedog");
URI xmlUri = new URI("http://www.mywebsite.com/getXMLInfo.xml");
```

// Prepares the request.
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet loginHttpGet = new HttpGet();
loginHttpGet.setURI(loginUri);

HttpGet xmlHttpGet = new HttpGet();
xmlHttpGet.setURI(xmlUri);

// Sends the request and read the response
HttpResponse loginResponse = httpClient.execute(loginHttpGet);
InputStream loginInputStream = loginResponse.getEntity().getContent();

HttpResponse xmlResponse = httpClient.execute(xmlHttpGet);
InputStream xmlInputStream = xmlResponse.getEntity().getContent();

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(xmlInputStream.toString()));

doc.getDocumentElement();
// Continue using DOM to parse my XML data
}

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate your how our "web session" is being maintained. I am going to guess it is via a session cookie. If so, use HttpClient and keep using the *same* `HttpClient` object for both requests. The session cookies will be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm actually not SURE what is being used, but I do believe it's with a session cookie.  So, ideally, I'd like to make a login post request, wait until the page starts to load, then immediately go ahead and make my xml request using a similar HttpClient request, but I'm not sure how to do this yet. Some example code would be something like:

Comment: (see above for some example code...I know it's not correct yet.  Any suggestions would be most helpful)

Comment: @Lee: Unless you have invented a time machine, that's not going to work, as the Web server may not have processed your login request by the time you ask it to start doing other stuff.

Comment: I think sometimes a time machine would be easier to invent!  I'm researching how to either put in a wait, wait onload, or wait onfinished loading.

Comment: Even if I put in a Thread.sleep(15000) command, it is not working.  With my above code do the cookies get handled correctly?  It is still acting like it's a different session.  I am totally stumped.